# Android waitForMonitorWithTimeout method not working

Tags: android

I am writing automated test cases using Instrumentation.  "waitforMonitorWithTimeout"
always timesout.  If I use waitForMonitor everything is fine.    The two lines
of code are below. (I comment out one of them when building my test project).

Activity currentActivity = instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, (long)30);

Activity currentActivity = instrumentation.waitForMonitor(monitor);

Are there known issues with "waitforMonitorWithTimeout"?   I have to use the timeout
to determine if an event occured (and thus transition to a new activity) or not.

Answer (score 7):

I found my problem - the documentation states that the delay is in **seconds**.  In fact the delay is in **milliseconds**.  (At least this is the case in the eclipse/Android realm).  When I used 30000 instead of 30 - trying to get a 30 second delay - things worked much better.

Comment: has anyone reported this as an issue?

Comment: it is 6 years gone since that time and bug still here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about *waitforMonitorWithTimeout*, but to check if an activity has been launched I do the following in my tests:

```
ActivityMonitor monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(
                  SomeActivity.class.getCanonicalName(), null, true);
//Do something, for example press a focused button
sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
//check the activity has been launched 1 time
assertTrue(getInstrumentation().checkMonitorHit(monitor, 1));
```

I hope it helps, even if it's not the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks but I've added checks using "checkMonitorHit" and its coming up false as well.  It seems as if the actual setting/hitting of the monitor isn't functioning when using "waitforMonitorWithTimeout".  Unfrotunately I can't use "waitforMonitor" (without the timeout) since the action causing the monitor to hit may or may not occur and I need to handle both scenarios.